# How can i get latest climate details JSON?

Tags: ios, json, maps, weather

Hi iam planning to create one App which will give latest climate information to normal users,so if any variation in climate then they can prepare for that and also avoid disaster .

But i dont know from wer i get these JSON with all details??
Please help..

I have tried this but its not helpful

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/01/11/12-json-weather-apis/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not on the issue, but I'll write a few of words. Actually not necessarily JSON. By your link you can see that the weather services to giving the data in XML exist more than in JSON. You can also use XML with a simple converter [simple converter](https://github.com/rsoldatenko/XMLConverter) . This is to expand your search.

*PS: In the examples, there is a code to convert answer in XML format from the weather service accuweather.com (possible change to another what you need).*

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org). You can make a simple `GET` request including the location in the URI for example:

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk`

Returns:

```
{ "base" : "gdps stations",
  "clouds" : { "all" : 12 },
  "cod" : 200,
  "coord" : { "lat" : 51.506399999999999,
      "lon" : -0.12719
    },
  "dt" : 1383042292,
  "id" : 2633993,
  "main" : { "grnd_level" : 1012.4400000000001,
      "humidity" : 93,
      "pressure" : 1012.4400000000001,
      "sea_level" : 1021.04,
      "temp" : 281.64800000000002,
      "temp_max" : 281.64800000000002,
      "temp_min" : 281.64800000000002
    },
  "name" : "London",
  "rain" : { "3h" : 0 },
  "sys" : { "country" : "United Kingdom",
      "sunrise" : 1383029402,
      "sunset" : 1383064700
    },
  "weather" : [ { "description" : "few clouds",
        "icon" : "02d",
        "id" : 801,
        "main" : "Clouds"
      } ],
  "wind" : { "deg" : 260.00099999999998,
      "speed" : 4.5599999999999996
    }
}
```

Is this any use to you?

Comment: Thanks but iam looking for world wide climate data.So i can list out everything in listview

Answer (score -1):

You can use accuweather api. It is most accurate in weather forcasting
It provides api for android & ios both

http://api.accuweather.com/

Comment: Thanks but iam looking for world wide climate data.So i can list out everything in listview

Comment: yes buddy accuweather is world wide. Even google is using accuweather in its new & weather apps. Once you get the data its upto you to display it

Comment: but its not a free one right,i have to pay for that